# Previously uploaded profile pic doesnot appear while updating profile leaving the upload input empty

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my controller file `Login.php` here I am fetching post data from the form which contains data of a vendor's profile there is to input for images one is profile pic other is company logo and rest data about name services etc.

When I upload a new pic it works fine, but if I try to update the profile by changing only company name then after clicking update button the previously uploaded profile pic disappears and the file name is also removed from the database.

```html
<?php

public  function profile() {
        
    $login_email = $this->session->userdata('email_id');
    $this->load->model('Vendormodel');
    $vendor = $this->input->post();
    print_r($vendor);
        

    $ppic['profile_pic'] = $this->Vendormodel->get_pic($login_email);
    $cpic['company_pic'] = $this->Vendormodel->get_cpic($login_email);
    $service_id = $this->input->post('service');
    unset($vendor['service']);
    $loc_id = $this->input->post('locations');
    unset($vendor['locations']);

    $id1 = $this->Vendormodel->get_vendor_id($login_email);
    if (isset($loc_id))
        foreach ($loc_id as $lid) {
            $post1[] = $this->Vendormodel->get_location($lid);
        }
    if (isset($loc_id))
        foreach ($post1 as $loc) {
            $this->Vendormodel->add_vendor_locations($id1, $loc);
        }
    $this->Vendormodel->add_vendor_profile($login_email, $vendor);
    print_r($vendor);

    if (isset($service_id))
        foreach ($service_id as $id) {
            $post[] = $this->Vendormodel->get_services($id);
        }
    if (isset($service_id))
        foreach ($post as $service) {
            $this->Vendormodel->add_vendor_services($id1, $service);
        }
    if ($_FILES) {
        $vendor['company_pic'] = $_FILES['company_pic']['name'];
        $vendor['profile_pic'] = $_FILES['profile_pic']['name'];
        $ppic['profile_pic'] = $_FILES['profile_pic']['name'];
        $cpic['company_pic'] = $_FILES['company_pic']['name'];
        $this->Vendormodel->update_pic($ppic['profile_pic'], $login_email);
        $this->Vendormodel->update_cpic($cpic['company_pic'], $login_email);
    }

    print_r($ppic);
    $config['upload_path'] = './vendors_pic/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jif|png|jpeg';
    $config['overwrite'] = false;
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $field = 'profile_pic';
    
    if ($this->upload->do_upload($field)) {
        $temp = $this->upload->data();
        $pic = $temp['file_name'];
    } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', "error uploading profile pic");
    }

    $config['upload_path'] = './vendors_pic/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jif|png|jpeg';
    $config['overwrite'] = false;
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $field1 = 'company_pic';
    
    if ($this->upload->do_upload($field1)) {
        
        $temp1 = $this->upload->data();
        $pic1 = $temp1['file_name'];
    } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', "error uploading company pic");
    }
    
    $vendordash['det'] = $this->Vendormodel->vendor_details($login_email);
    $this->session->set_userdata('name', $vendordash['det']->first_name);
    $vendordash['services'] = $this->Vendormodel->vendor_services($id1);
    $vendordash['locations'] = $this->Vendormodel->vendor_locations($id1);
    $this->load->view('vendor/pro_header', $ppic);
    $this->load->view('vendor/vendor_dashboard', $vendordash);
}
?>
```